# I set my TV to 'extend' my laptop and to be primary display but

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, hdmi, tv

I set my TV to 'extend' my laptop screen and to be the primary display, but the TV won't display the primary duplicate display - I'm left with a laptop which just shows an area of blank screen.

I can't change the setting away from duplicate as I cannot see anything on the laptop. If I right-click and select Catalyst Graphics Software, it appears where the TV should show it.

Any ideas how to fix this? I want the TV to only show what is on the laptop, not to extend the screen.

Comment: Hm.. Does your laptop have a FN button that toggles external display modes?

Comment: it did but i broke the keyboard now im using external one without fn button.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> and select **Duplicate**.